Modbus (RTU_CLIENT) on zephyr
I am trying to fetch data from Selec energy meter which uses MOdbus protocol . Attaching Instruction Manual. https://www.selec.com/viewdocument/0bed45bd5774ffddc95ffe500024f628
`Here this energy meter is Master having device ID 1 .
I am using nucleo_stm32h563zi with zephyr to fetch. But I am getting failed repeatedly .
My code
#include <zephyr/kernel.h>
#include <zephyr/sys/util.h>
#include <zephyr/drivers/gpio.h>
#include <zephyr/modbus/modbus.h>

#include <zephyr/logging/log.h>




static int client_iface;

const static struct modbus_iface_param client_param = {
    .mode = MODBUS_MODE_RTU,
    .rx_timeout = 50000,
    .serial = {
        .baud = 9600,  // Set to 9600 if needed
        .parity = UART_CFG_PARITY_NONE,
        .stop_bits_client = UART_CFG_STOP_BITS_1,
    },
};


#define MODBUS_NODE DT_COMPAT_GET_ANY_STATUS_OKAY(zephyr_modbus_serial)
LOG_MODULE_REGISTER(main, LOG_LEVEL_DBG);
static int init_modbus_client(void)
{
    const char iface_name[] = {DEVICE_DT_NAME(MODBUS_NODE)};
    client_iface = modbus_iface_get_by_name(iface_name);
    return modbus_init_client(client_iface, client_param);
}

int main(void)
{

    float reg_buffer[17] = {0.0};
    uint16_t address = 0x00;

    printk("Initialized RTU\n");
    if (init_modbus_client()) {
        printk("Modbus RTU client initialization failed\n");
        return 0;
    }


    while (true) {

        int err = modbus_read_holding_regs_fp(client_iface, 1, address, reg_buffer, 17);
        if (err) {
            printk("Failed to read at 0x%X: FC03 error %d\n", address, err);
        } else {
            printk("Read successful:\n");
        }

        k_msleep(10);  // Delay before the next cycle to avoid overwhelming the Modbus bus
    }
    return 0;
}

my app.overlay file
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2020 Phytec Messtechnik GmbH
 *
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */

&arduino_serial {
    status = "okay";
    current-speed = <9600>;
    modbus0 {
        compatible = "zephyr,modbus-serial";
        status = "okay";
        de-gpios = <&arduino_header 13 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;   /* D7 */
        re-gpios = <&arduino_header 8 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;    /* D2 */
    };
};

This is my Logs
*** Booting Zephyr OS build v4.0.0-1160-g8faa486430db ***
Initialized RTU
[00:00:00.000,000] <inf> modbus_serial: RTU timeout 4010 us
[00:00:00.050,000] <wrn> modbus: Client wait-for-RX timeout
Failed to read at 0x0: FC03 error -116
[00:00:00.110,000] <wrn> modbus: Client wait-for-RX timeout
Failed to read at 0x0: FC03 error -116
[00:00:00.170,000] <wrn> modbus: Client wait-for-RX timeout
Failed to read at 0x0: FC03 error -116
[00:00:00.230,000] <wrn> modbus: Client wait-for-RX timeout
Failed to read at 0x0: FC03 error -116
[00:00:00.290,000] <wrn> modbus: Client wait-for-RX timeout
Failed to read at 0x0: FC03 error -116

My Logic Analyzer has giving me this


The Logic Analyser decode of the message says Invalid Checksum! which could explain the modbus errors. Have you checked if checksum generation in the software is configured correctly?
